# sql Combining two sub queries and summing the total

Tags: sql

I have two queries. Both return

```
 select sum (Amount) as 'Less then 30 days', [Fluids Management$Cust_ Ledger    Entry].[Customer No_]
FROM [Fluids Management$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry]
group by [Fluids Management$Cust_ Ledger Entry].[Customer No_]


 select sum ([Debit Amount]) as 'Less then 30 days', [Fluids Management$Cust_ Ledger Entry].[Customer No_]
 FROM [Fluids Management$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry]
  group by [Fluids Management$Cust_ Ledger Entry].[Customer No_]
```

both have more indepth criteria , i just didn't include it.  Anyways i want to take the first query and check if the customer no exists in the second query. and if so add the sum of amount to the debit amount. if the id doesn't show up in the second query just return the sum in the first query. its all groupded by a customer no.  Help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eaiset way would probably a SUM on a inlined UNION query

```
SELECT SUM (AMOUNT), [Customer No_]
FROM 

(
 select Amount 
          [Fluids Management$Cust_ Ledger    Entry].[Customer No_]
FROM 
        [Fluids Management$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry]
UNION ALL 
select [Debit Amount] as 'Less then 30 days', 
         [Fluids Management$Cust_ Ledger Entry].[Customer No_]
 FROM [Fluids Management$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry]
) 

GROUP BY  [Customer No_]
```

You didn't specify database so you might need to alias the Inline View in order for it to work

Comment: i don't think that will work. because i need the grouping in each individual queries , not the total sum.  then add the amount of each grouping to a grouping of debit amounts that match customer no.. also you have two columns your selecting inside with no grouping.. that doesn't even work

Comment: @Sirus The only issue that I see is if the second query includes customers that aren't in the first. However if you really want you've described you'll need to specify the DB since the syntax varies

Comment: The first query will return sum of amount per customer no.  So 
1000 | C00033
2323 | C00034

the second query will return sum of debit amount per customer no. So
1000 | C0033

but might not have the 2323 | C00034

So i would then just like returned 
2323 | C00034
2000 | C00033

there both in the same table , same db etc

Comment: @Sirus Ok. That's fine. Then it will just return the sumed values from the first query. Isn't that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Put both queries in Derived Tables and LEFT JOIN them:

```
SELECT a.[Customer No_], a.'Less then 30 days' + COALESCE(b.'Less then 30 days', 0)
FROM
 (
   SELECT SUM (Amount) AS 'Less then 30 days', [Fluids Management$Cust_ Ledger Entry].[Customer No_]
   FROM [Fluids Management$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry]
   GROUP BY [Fluids Management$Cust_ Ledger Entry].[Customer No_]
 ) AS a
LEFT JOIN
 (
   SELECT SUM ([Debit Amount]) AS 'Less then 30 days', [Fluids Management$Cust_ Ledger Entry].[Customer No_]
   FROM [Fluids Management$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry]
   GROUP BY [Fluids Management$Cust_ Ledger Entry].[Customer No_]
 ) AS b
ON a.[Customer No_] = b.[Customer No_]
```

But as you access the same table twice you might be able to change it to a single query using SUM(CASE)